# Callback after iteration is completed in meteor template

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Using meteorjs and its templating solution, I need to execute a JavaScript function (as part of callback function), right after the template and the **loop** to render a dynamic elements (reading from mongodb) is complete.
What is the right approach in meteorjs for this matter?

Comment: [Deps.afterFlush()](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_afterflush) can schedule a function to run after all currently invalidated reactive functions.  If that is not what you are after, maybe post some example code.

Comment: thank you for the clue, the sample code is exactly same as what Peppe (in first answer) below. I am not sure how to use afterFlush -- if you think that's still the answer ... would you mind to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like the [rendered callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) would do the job.

```html
<template name="main">
    {{> renderCollection}}
</template>
```

```html
<template name="renderCollection">
    {{#each theCursor}}
        {{someField}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.renderCollection.rendered = function(){
    console.log("The collection has just been rendered!")
}
```

Comment: this rendered event is triggerred even when the collection is not completely rendered inside DOM :(

Comment: @iwan So what you really want is to wait till a subscription is ready (so all the documents been sent to the client)?